# Getting a warning on Runtime errors when converting a winform to Excel.Application

Tags: winforms, excel

I have the following code on my windows form application. The code opens Excel on a particular worksheet:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On    

Private Sub UserStatsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UserStatsToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

        Try
            'get an existing excel.application object
            **xlApp = CType(CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Application), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)** ' Getting Error here
        Catch ex As Exception
            'no existing excel.application object - create a new one

            xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

        End Try

        Dim xlWBName As String = "HRSC Queue Analytics"
        Dim xlBookPath As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

        xlApp.Visible = True


    End Sub
```

I am getting the warning: Runtime errors occur when converting System.Windows.Forms.Application to Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel.Application. I am not trying to convert the form, I am trying to open Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with

```
Imports XLSApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Private Sub UserStatsToolStripMenuItem_Click(....)
    Dim xlApp As XLSApp
    Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

    Try

        xlApp = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), XLSApp)
```

From the error message seems that the compiler cannot decide if you are referring to the System.Windows.Forms.Application class or to the Excel one. You could use an import alias to redefine the name of the Excel class and avoid the long typing and give a clear hint about the class that you want to get with the CType function